# How to use datalist in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding

I am new in mvc. i am working with mvc project .it's a shopping cart project. In asp.net web forms we used data list control and we also set a RepeatColumns property like 5,10,20.  What is alternate to that in MVC? Can I use the same control in MVC as well?

so can any one please tell me how to show my data in data list control?

Answer (score 1):

To have five product Image in one row you can use two loops and do this in razor syntax....

```
<div>
<table>
@for(int i = 0; i <= (Model.Count - 1) / 5; ++i)  /*Five is no of product record count per row*/
{
 <tr>
 for(int j = 0; j < 5 && i + j < Model.Count; ++j) {
  <td style="width:240px;margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;"> /*Adjust based on your HTML and CSS requeirment*/
   <img src="@Product.ImageSource" alt="drawing" />
   <Div>@Product.Title</Div>     
  </td>
 }
 </tr>
}
</table>
</div>
```

Above can be used to produce 5 Product Images per row....

Answer (score 0):

well theoretically there are no server controls available in asp.net MVC.. For learning you can check what are the [other differences in asp.net web form and MVC](http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2010/03/11/webforms-vs-mvc-again/) peradigm and must read [this link](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_MvcForWebFormsDevs.html). So you get overview what you can do and can't in MVC.

Now to display repeatable data in MVC you need to use LOOP and presant usign HTML helpers. You can adopt RAZOR syntax or Asp.net Syntax to show the data.

E.g in Razor you can have something like following to mimic the Repeater requirements.

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h3>Auctions</h3>
    </header>

    <ul id="auctions">

    @foreach(var auction in Model.Auctions) {
        <li>
            <h4 class="title">
                <a href="@auction.Url">@auction.Title</a>
            </h4>
        </li>
    }

    </ul>
</div>
```

TO quickly learn what is MVC and how to do Bookbinding you can refer [Music Store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) by Microsoft that explains basic necessarily things for MVC learner.

You question is little off topic but I love to answer them. ;) Happy coding

Comment: hi i use your way but i don't get exact output which i wont. so please give me another solution. i wont to show my product in horizontally 5 in 1 row. if you have any idea then give it's argent work

Comment: Post your HTML syntax and I will post RAZOR syntax for the same.

Comment: Another side note... This is altogether a new question.. Please don't mix up the things on SO and put it as new question I will try to answer them as well.